# Change what submit button does based on editorFor circumstance

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an edit form page on my website that allows users to edit quantities, on this page I used editorFor's which look like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.item_qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { min = 0, @class = "form-control" } })
```

And I have a submit button that looks like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" />
```

I want to make it so that if the user increases the qty, it will go ahead and run the post method. But on the other hand, if a user was to decrease the qty, I would want the save button to look like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="confirm()" class="btn" />
```

Where it gets the user to confirm before running the post.

How can I make my save button change based on what the user types into the editorFor?

Here is my entire view page as requested

```
@model PIC_Program_1._0.Models.JODetails
@using PIC_Program_1._0.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    PIC_Program_1_0Context db = new PIC_Program_1_0Context();

    var currentData = db.JODetails.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(j => j.ID == Model.ID);
    Component comp = db.Components.Find(Model.ComponentID);
    Item i = db.Items.Find(Model.ItemID);
}

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function clicked(e) {

        if(@i != null ) {
                var itemDiff = // model - new editorfor value;
                if (!confirm('Are you sure? Doing this will reduce item ' + @i.ItemID + ' future stock to ' + itemDiff))e.preventDefault();
            }

        }

        function OnChangeEvent(){
          alert("value is changed");

            var itemQty = $('#itemQTY').val();          
            if (itemQty < @Model.item_qty) {
                btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clicked(event)");
            }

        }


    </script>

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>JODetails</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.subDetail)

        <p style="color:red">@ViewBag.Error</p>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemID, "ItemID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item_qty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (ViewBag.isValid == false)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item_qty, new { disabled = "disabled", @Value = Model.item_qty, @readonly = "readonly" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item_qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent()", min = 0, @class = "form-control" @id = "itemQTY"} })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item_qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: I posted below the changes I made and tested them in another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the on change you can on your editor for:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.item_qty, new {  htmlAttributes = new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent(this)", min = 0, @class = "form-control", @id ="someId" } })

<script type="text/javascript">
 function OnChangeEvent(){
    var itemQty = $('#someID').val(); //This will give you value of editor for
    alert("new value is: " + itemQty);
    //Call some controller function here and do your increase/decrease logic and return value so we know what to do. also perform your save in controller too if needed.
    @Model.IsChanged = true;
    //do other functions here also like change button
    //if decrease add below
    btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirm()");
    //if increase remove and perform save.
 }
</script>
```

You can also change the button from that method. There is no good way to do on call events at a server level, unless using blazor, so javascript is your best bet here.

Updated answer per OP:

```
@model PIC_Program_1._0.Models.JODetails
@using PIC_Program_1._0.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    PIC_Program_1_0Context db = new PIC_Program_1_0Context();

    var currentData = db.JODetails.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(j => j.ID == Model.ID);
    Component comp = db.Components.Find(Model.ComponentID);
    Item i = db.Items.Find(Model.ItemID);
}


<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>JODetails</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.subDetail)

        <p style="color:red">@ViewBag.Error</p>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemID, "ItemID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item_qty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (ViewBag.isValid == false)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item_qty, new { disabled = "disabled", @Value = Model.item_qty, @readonly = "readonly" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item_qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent(this)", min = 0, @class = "form-control", @id = "itemQTY"} })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item_qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function OnChangeEvent(){
          alert("value is changed");

            var itemQty = $('#itemQTY').val();          
            if (itemQty < @Model.item_qty) {
                btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clicked(event)");
            }

        }


</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how I can get the new value that the user entered?

Comment: @JoshFontaine I have updated code to carry the value of your EditorFor. But basically just give you EditorFor an id and call it in the JS and you can then pass it to controller and do whatever you need with it. You could also use jQuery functions too if you are more familiar with them.

Comment: thanks for the help! But unfortunately this isn't working for me. I can't even get the alert

Comment: This is pretty basic Javascript stuff. Can you post the code for the entire page view? Perhaps something is wrong there I can see. I modified the editfor. I didn't have it formatted correctly assuming you would know, but I have now changed it.

Comment: Okay I added it in now

Comment: @JoshFontaine I tested your code in my own project. I typed in something to editor for and tabbed out and the alert window popped up, so I can say this is 100% working assuming you are running latest .net framework or core at least. I have pasted it in above, and below my original answer.

Comment: @JoshFontaine did this help?

Comment: Happy to hear. Upvote and mark solution would be appreciated:)